# Instance member 'fileDataRepresentation' cannot be used on type 'AVCapturePhoto'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, capture, avcapture, avcapturephotooutput

Swift gives the error that a fileDataRepresentation cannot be created for AVCapturePhoto. Printing "photo", returns the photo's metadata. How can I convert the image to file bytes and eventually base64? I have tried many methods so far, but all rely on obtaining file bytes. Thanks for any responses in advance!

```
   @IBAction func takePhotoButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
          let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
          let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
          let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
                               kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
                               kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160]
          settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
          settings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = false
          sessionOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
        
    }

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Swift.Error?) {
        let imageData = AVCapturePhoto.fileDataRepresentation()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AVCapturePhoto.fileDataRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephoto/2873919-filedatarepresentation) is an `instance` method, NOT a `class` method.

You have to call it on an instance of `AVCapturePhoto` like this -

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Swift.Error?) {
    let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()
}
```

Comment: This method and converting it to a base64 image is creating a corrupt image. Is there any way to solve this? Code: let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData!) let pngImage = uiImage?.pngData()
        let base64Data = pngImage!.base64EncodedString()

Comment: You should be able to convert this data into base64 string directly like `let base64String = photo.fileDataRepresentation()?.base64EncodedString()`. There's no need to go through this route `image > pngData > base64`.